# php-cuong customer avatar customer profile image

Tags: magento2.2, customer

I am getting an error, In admin panel when clicking on `customers-> All customers`, it is throwing an error

> Class
>   PHPCuong\CustomerProfilePicture\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Avatar
>   does not exist

Comment: does that file exist?

Comment: Yes it is exists:

Comment: https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-customer-avatar/tree/master/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns

Comment: Check if the extension is properly installed. Try clearing the cache and running `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

Comment: The extension is properly installed. cleared cache & run the command php bin/magento setup:di:compile.  still getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need to put extension file on this paht.

> app\code\PHPCuong\CustomerProfilePicture

2. Run this commands from CLI.

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   ```

Comment: executed the above commands . the error remain same

Comment: Confirm that that file is exist on same path.
Can you specify where is file exist into your system.

Comment: Yes . file path is exist :    /magento_root_folder/app/code/php-cuong/magento2-customer-avatar/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Avatar.php

Comment: you need to put extnsion like this way. app\code\PHPCuong\CustomerProfilePicture.

So your file path is something like this : app/code/PHPCuong/CustomerProfilePicture/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Avatar.php

Comment: Below is the link contains code it is refering : https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-customer-avatar/blob/master/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Avatar.php

Comment: that specify name space like this : PHPCuong\CustomerProfilePicture\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns

So try what I said and then check, your issues need solve.

Comment: Now am not able to find the upload option for customer profile image in admin section.  as it should be available under customer > Edit > Account Information Tab. But it is not displayed.  Help me to resolve this

Comment: first check that is there any error show into the log file or something?

Comment: In log file, it displays when upload the profile image from frontend. main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/en_US/Magento_Customer/js/zxcvbn.js.map' [] []

Comment: Can you try to run compile command ones and then check?

Comment: Its not worked.

Comment: cloned from different repo :  https://github.com/euknyaz/magento2-customer-avatar-sm    . Now it is displayed upload option .

Comment: Now not able to save the customer image.   There is no error in log file.  but in front end getting error like  Request URL: https://domain.com/admin/customer/index/validate/key/2efebe1cd44c002a7b2cf86adb52cd3a874ddedfd6d7f36d82acf33a0c690299/?isAjax=true
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: check what the error, so it show 500 internal server error.

Comment: am getting erro in log file like below:   main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  
 {"method":"GET","url":"https://domainname.com/admin/customer/index/edit/id/2/key/aa48a95134c311863c38f2bd20a57041d875263b765aad2f238ece6e790adfa6/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []

Comment: It looks like problem with customer save from admin section:  for any other field also getting error :  A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.

Comment: Now able to resolve the save profile image issue. Thank you support @Dhiren Vasoya

Comment: you are most welcome :)